# Is there a way to enable "noninteractive" from within a powershell session

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I have an orchestration mechanism (bamboo server) that will launch my ps1 script.

However it launches the script without the -noninteractive argument to powershell.exe.

This in turn makes all my scripts halt and await user interaction.

Atlassian does not want to change their launch mechanism, so im left to figure out if I can somehow manipulate my powershell session from "within".

Question is this:
Is there any way I can make my powershell session change to "non interactive mode" when it have already been launched?

Comment: I don't know if that's possible, but from within your script, you could simply launch PowerShell again in non-interactive mode, giving it the name of your own script (plus a parameter to make sure that doesn't loop, of course). Clumsy and it may not play nice with I/O redirection, but it's a thought.

Comment: I don't understand the sentence "This [i.e., the use of `-NonInteractive`] in turn makes all my scripts halt and await user interaction." The `-NonInteractive` parameter makes PowerShell terminate a script that prompts for input; it doesn't force user interaction.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart 
"without"

Trick is to read the line above:
"However it launches the script without the -noninteractive argument to powershell.exe" <- THIS

Comment: Ah, the opposite of what I thought you said. You can of course have a script re-launch itself in non-interactive mode (as Jeroen Mostert said), but in that case the script will simply abort. The real question: What is prompting in your script and causing it to halt when not running interactively? Fix that and your script won't halt.

Comment: "What is prompting in your script and causing it to halt when not running interactively"
We have about 6 modules with > 400 cmdlets that we change on a daily basis. What we see is that when we add a parameter somewhere and it down the callchain gets called without the new arg, it simply halts.
This happens about once a week and the amount of time we use to find it is large.
If instead it simply throws an exception, we would be able to see it in the callstack.

Comment: In my case the problem was that bamboo would occasionally farm my job to agents without the appropriate credentials and the login attempt would fail and try to prompt (yes this is an agent capability issue but the build shouldn't hang because of it). Technically, this is also an issue with the powershell "convention" that says prompting is the right thing to do instead of just erroring (and not making it optional at that level).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to perform this within the session.

There is a workaround for creating a new session, as defined by Bill.

Answer (score 2):

Would a solution like this work for you?

```
# Returns $true if current PS instance started with -NonInteractive parameter
function Test-NonInteractive {
  foreach ( $arg in [Environment]::GetCommandLineArgs() ) {
    if ( $arg -like "-noni*" ) {
      return $true
    }
  }
  return $false
}

if ( -not (Test-NonInteractive) ) {
  $scriptArgs = ""
  $args | ForEach-Object {
    if ( $scriptArgs -eq "" ) {
      $scriptArgs = '"{0}"' -f $_
    }
    else {
      $scriptArgs = ' "{0}"' -f $_
    }
  }
  $params = @{
    "FilePath" = "powershell.exe"
    "ArgumentList"  = @(
      "-ExecutionPolicy Bypass"
      "-NonInteractive"
      "-File ""{0}""" -f $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
      $scriptArgs
    )
  }
  Start-Process @params
  return
}

# ...rest of script logic here...
```

This script relaunches itself with the `-NonInteractive` parameter and whatever parameters you passed to the script.

Comment: gave you an upvote for effort, but no, that is not a viable solution in any sense of the word.

Comment: Why is the solution not viable?

Comment: Basically you lose all the session variables from host session when doing that

Comment: furthermore you get another exception stack

Comment: furthermore it doesnt answer the question posed which specifically states: 'make my powershell session change to "non interactive mode"'.
It doesnt change the session, it creates a new session.

Comment: furthermore the IO redirects gets screwed up

Comment: Furthermore it does not guarentee to start the new session with the same parameters as the host session

Comment: Correct; it creates a new session. It's a workaround. The idea here is you would use this as a "launcher" script to run other scripts. (I agree it's not viable to add this code as a preamble to all of your automation scripts!)

Comment: Most of our automation is run through bamboo and we rely heavily on all of the above. 
Dont get me wrong champ, its a solid workaround, but not a solution to the question.
The reason for the upvote i gave and the reason for not marking it as an answer